# listview and keyboard navigation

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-fragmentactivity

**What i have done :**

In my application there is a Fragment Activity (The parent Activity) which launches a fragment and on that fragment there is button on click of which Another Activity launching which has custom listview.

**Problem:**
 When I navigate listview using keyboard it does not show highlighted state but, if i remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from listview it shows highlighted state but does not support onclick item of that listview.

Comment: set all `focusable` items focusability to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys I am done with the problem.The solution is to add one state in selector.xml i.e. 'android:state_activated="true"'

Answer (score 1):

If there are `focusable` views in *row.xml* of your `ListView` add these attribute to each `view`

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: can you post the whole `xml` file.

Comment: Thank you guys I am done with the problem.The solution is to add one state in selector.xml i.e. 'android:state_activated="true"'